# How to rotate SVG path of a line 90 degrees

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm not sure what else to do to make this work. I'm trying to rotate a line 90' in a Path.

I've set the transform to rotate(90deg).

Here is my code:

```css
 
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 #A {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #A1A1A1;
  background: #E5E5E5;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 #Line_28 {
  opacity: 1;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: rgb(0, 68, 253);
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  stroke-miterlimit: 4;
  shape-rendering: auto;
 }
 .Line_28 {
  transform: matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  overflow: visible;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 1px;
 }
 #Line_29 {
  opacity: 1;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: rgb(253, 0, 0);
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  stroke-miterlimit: 4;
  shape-rendering: auto;
 }
 .Line_29 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  overflow: visible;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 30px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<body>
<div id="A">
 <svg viewBox="0 0 30 1" data-name="Line 28" data-type="Line" class="Line_28">
  <path id="Line_28" d="M 0 0 L 30 0">
  </path>
 </svg>
 <svg viewBox="0 0 30 1" data-name="Line 29" data-type="Line" class="Line_29">
  <path id="Line_29" d="M 0 0 L 30 0">
  </path>
 </svg>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The SVG should look like this.

[image]

The red line is Line 29.

Comment: set bigger `width` and you will see the `rotate` line

Comment: @לבנימלכה Set width bigger where?

Comment: see my answer please

Comment: Did we answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

If you apply `transform: rotate(90deg);` to Line_28 it will rotate.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 #A {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #A1A1A1;
  background: #E5E5E5;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 #Line_28 {
  opacity: 1;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: rgb(0, 68, 253);
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  stroke-miterlimit: 4;
  shape-rendering: auto;
 }
 .Line_28 {
  transform: matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  overflow: visible;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 1px;
 }
 #Line_29 {
  opacity: 1;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: rgb(253, 0, 0);
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  stroke-miterlimit: 4;
  shape-rendering: auto;
 }
 .Line_29 {
  overflow: visible;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 30px;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<body>
<div id="A">
 <svg viewBox="0 0 30 1" data-name="Line 28" data-type="Line" class="Line_28">
  <path id="Line_28" d="M 0 0 L 30 0">
  </path>
 </svg>
 <svg viewBox="0 0 30 1" data-name="Line 29" data-type="Line" class="Line_29">
  <path id="Line_29" d="M 0 0 L 30 0">
  </path>
 </svg>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've updated the post and added an image that it is the red line that is supposed to be rotated. But you've got the blue line to rotate. So why does that work?

Comment: OK so it looks like it works with the blue line because none of the position or size values have changed. Where in the red line I'm settinh the post transformed size and position.

Answer (score 2):

Because you set `rotate(90deg)` you have to use `width` like it's `height`(and the `height` become to be `width`)

So set `.Line_29 {...left: 10px;width: 30px;}`

```css
 
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 #A {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #A1A1A1;
  background: #E5E5E5;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 #Line_28 {
  opacity: 1;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: rgb(0, 68, 253);
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  stroke-miterlimit: 4;
  shape-rendering: auto;
 }
 .Line_28 {
  transform: matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  overflow: visible;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 1px;
 }
 #Line_29 {
  opacity: 1;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: rgb(253, 0, 0);
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  stroke-miterlimit: 4;
  shape-rendering: auto;
 }
 .Line_29 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  overflow: visible;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<body>
<div id="A">
 <svg viewBox="0 0 30 1" data-name="Line 28" data-type="Line" class="Line_28">
  <path id="Line_28" d="M 0 0 L 30 0">
  </path>
 </svg>
 <svg viewBox="0 0 30 1" data-name="Line 29" data-type="Line" class="Line_29">
  <path id="Line_29" d="M 0 0 L 30 0">
  </path>
 </svg>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```